# PySide Splitter sizing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QTreeView` and a `PlainTextEdit` aligned horizontally in a splitter.  Both widgets take up the same amount of space, how can I make it so that one will be wider than the other, but still be able to re-size the widget by dragging the splitter handles?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a stretch factor to the columns of your splitter. The widget with the higher factor will take more space than the other.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setStretchFactor.